# openssl input in hexadecimal for bash

Tags: bash, openssl, sha, hmac, digest

How do we input value and key as hexadecimal values?

```
echo -n "value" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "key"
$value=11111111FFAA2211
$key=11111111FFAA2211000000000011BBFF
echo -n "$value" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "$key"
```

is not working either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just managed to solved it, it's the use of the '-macopt hexkey:string' option.

`echo -n '4869205468657265' | xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha512 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b`

(stdin)= 87aa7cdea5ef619d4ff0b4241a1d6cb02379f4e2ce4ec2787ad0b30545e17cdedaa833b7d6b8a702038b274eaea3f4e4be9d914eeb61f1702e696c203a126854

or

`key='0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b'`
`value='4869205468657265'`
`echo -n "$value" | xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha512 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:$key`

(stdin)= 87aa7cdea5ef619d4ff0b4241a1d6cb02379f4e2ce4ec2787ad0b30545e17cdedaa833b7d6b8a702038b274eaea3f4e4be9d914eeb61f1702e696c203a126854

I hope this answer may serve as a mini tutorial to help people.

Comment: I see that you mainly solved the problem with the key. But what about the input value? How do you convert 11111111FFAA2211 into 4869205468657265?